# How to use multiple global middlewares in node.js using TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I need to have a few global middlewares in my Node.JS app. 
That's how they both looking:

```
public app: express.Application; 
....
this.app = express();
....
let tokenFilter = async function filtering(req, res, next) {
    //logic
};
let allowOnlyJson = bodyParser.json({
    type: "*/*"
});
```

That's how I using them:

```
app.use(tokenFilter);
app.use(allowOnlyJson);
```

But this not works. How should I pass them both?
I can't find a similar question here, all of them about specific cases.

**EDIT 1**

Ok, I've found the way how to use a few middlewares [here](https://blog.budiharso.info/2015/07/28/Combine-multiple-express-middleware/):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var connect = require('connect'); // we require connect

function middleware1(req, res, next) {
  // snip...
}

function middleware2(req, res, next) {
  // snip...
}

function handleRequest(req, res) {
  // snip...
}

var combinedMiddleware = (function() {
  var chain = connect();
  [middleware1, middleware2].forEach(function(middleware) {
    chain.use(middleware);
  });
  return chain;
})();
```

Then you will be able to pass `combinedMiddleware` to  `this.app.use(combinedMiddleware);` method.

But how can add this one as additional middleware?

```
bodyParser.json({
    type: "*/*"
});
```

Comment: Put them on the `exports` object? E.g. `exports.tokenFilter = async...`

Comment: @Michael yes, something like that. I've updated an answer

Comment: Is this all in the same file? What do you mean it doesn't work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: How is your logic? Are you calling next() at the end of your logic? If  you don't call next the request ends. You want to call next() to move to the next router

Comment: @Bergur yes, I calling next() if token valid, if not I send 401 status code

Comment: @Bergur If I put only one of the filter above then all works well, but if they are both present - no one doesn't work